# Recursive (batch) video codec details with MediaInfo CLI

Tags: scripting, python, video, batch-jobs, codec

I want to share my script to do this with Media Info CLI and python. At first I tried with pure bash but should have just gone python at first, much quicker and adaptable (for me).

My task was to recursively go through all files in a specified folder (in this case on a NAS), and print as well as store in a txt file all the video codec and profile level used in each.

The reason be I found some older Samsung TV wont play H264 with profile level greater than 4.1 , so some re-encoding was in order, also the latest Samsung TV have dropped support for xvid/divx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> usage: ./your_script_name.py ./your_path | tee output.txt

if you want different/additional details from media info check those available with "mediainfo --Info-Parameters"

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from glob import glob
import os
import sys
import subprocess

codecSummary = set() #dictionary


path = sys.argv[1]
print(path)

files = [f for f in glob(path+'/**', recursive=True) if os.path.isfile(f)]

#print(files)

for file in files:
        result = subprocess.check_output('mediainfo "'+file+'" "--Inform=Video;%Format% %Format_Profile%"', shell=True).decode().rstrip()

        if result:
                codecSummary.add(result)
                print(result + ' '+ file)
```

print(codecSummary)

Comment: +1. nice idea, but you might want to look into [pymediainfo](https://pymediainfo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), a library module which allows python programs to gather the same information without having to fork an external program (mediainfo) and then parse the text results.   If you're running debian (or ubuntu, etc) you can install it with `sudo apt install python3-pymediainfo`.  Other distros may have it packaged too, with a similar package name.

Comment: hey cool, thanks for the suggestion